# Making PayPal balance payments without being redirected to the PayPal site

Tags: api, rest, paypal

After reading the new [PayPal REST API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/), I've concluded that it still is **not** possible to integrate PayPal in a way that would allow clients to make payments from their PayPal balance without being redirected to PayPal's site. Is this correct? I wanted to check with the rest of the community to confirm that this is still the case.

Comment: Wouldn't that require the user to send his/her paypal credentials to/through your site? I don't think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Nope. That's what OAuth is for.

Comment: Yes, but your suggestion sounds like you are trying to circumvent OAuth. I guess I am not really sure what your intentions are.

Comment: We're building a web application where some users might make several small purchases per day. We're trying to minimize the friction involved. Instead of approving each payment individually, it would be nice if all payments could be pre-approved. Essentially, the user would be authorizing the web application to approve payments on their behalf. This would allow for one-click purchases (well okay, not *one* click, since Amazon owns that – maybe *two* clicks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To pre-approve a certain, limited amount sounds reasonable. This raises quite some implementational concerns on paypals side, I can imagine, but sounds like a decent request. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's correct. Even with the new REST APIs, you would still have to redirect the user to PayPal for them to login and approve the payment. There is no support for embedded (lighbox/mini-browser) flow yet in the new REST APis.

Comment: Thanks Praveen! I just wanted to make sure. I love the new APIs and documentation, by the way. Also, you say there is no support *yet*. Is this something that's being discussed?

Comment: yup it is. no date yet though.